# Generative adversarial networks tanh?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I was wondering, why in most of the models of GAN (in MNIST at least) I saw, the activation function (for the discriminator and the generator) was tanh ?
Isn't ReLu more efficient ? (I always read that for predictive networks)

Thanks!

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide a link to a paper or some code so everyone knows exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: Have you found a satisfying answer? I am looking for the answer as well.

Answer (score 10):

From the DCGAN paper [Radford et al. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06434.pdf]...

"The ReLU activation (Nair & Hinton, 2010) is used in the generator with the exception of the output
layer which uses the Tanh function. We observed that using a bounded activation allowed the model
to learn more quickly to saturate and cover the color space of the training distribution.  Within the
discriminator we found the leaky rectified activation (Maas et al., 2013) (Xu et al., 2015) to work
well, especially for higher resolution modeling. This is in contrast to the original GAN paper, which
used the maxout activation (Goodfellow et al., 2013)."

It could be that the symmetry of tanh is an advantage here, since the network should be treating darker colours and lighter colours in a symmetric way.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes it depends on the range that you want the activations to fall into. Whenever you hear "gates" in ML literature, you'll probably see a sigmoid, which is between 0 and 1. In this case, maybe they want activations to fall between -1 and 1, so they use tanh. [This page](https://github.com/soumith/ganhacks) says to use tanh, but they don't give an explanation. [DCGAN](https://github.com/Newmu/dcgan_code) uses ReLUs or leaky ReLUs except for the output of the generator. Makes sense - what if half of your embedding becomes zeros? Might be better to have a smoothly varying embedding between -1 and 1.

I'd love to hear someone else's input, as I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Why if they use a sigmoid for the last layer, they would want to fall into -1 and 1 in the previous layer ?
Can't sigmoid handle ReLu output ? (In example, in a mlp, I already used ReLu for the middle layer and sigmoid in the end and there was no problems at all)
But I think I understand. Indeed, if you have a lot of zeros in the embedding, the pixels generated will be all whites..
(But in this case, why DCGAN uses ReLus)
Thanks again!

Comment: I think this thread has already discussed it. http://surl.li/bnmrh